# Node SASS: @Import CSS from SCSS and AMP validation

Tags: css, sass, node-sass, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I have a assets/scss/main.scss file in which I import from a CSS.

`@import "assets/scss/header.css"`

The compiled file does not include the styles code from assets/scss/header.css, add the code:

`@import "assets/scss/header.css"`

but this compiled CSS **does not pass AMP Validation**.

Can anyone tell me how I could compile this file so that it adds the styles and not the @import?

I have tried to remove the extension to the file, like this:

`@import "assets/scss/header"`

and it worked but, then it wouldn't compile if you included another SCSS with the same name:

`@import "assets/scss/_header.scss"`

can someone help me?

I expected that compiling assets/scss/main.scss with `@import "assets/scss/header.css"` would add the CSS code and not `@import "assets/scss/header.css"` itself.